# How to set a handler for binding JSON fields which has a variety of naming styles to a POJO

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Springboot 2.5.1, Jackson 2.13.1

Input JSON looks like:

```
{
  "hello_word": "you are welcome",
  "my-name": "Meow",
  "Age": 11
}
```

Java POJO:

```
@Data
class A {

  private String helloWorld;

  private String myName;

  private Integer age;
}
```

Expected binding result:

```
class A {

  private String helloWorld = "you are welcome";

  private String myName = "Meow";

  private Integer age = 11;
}
```

As you can see, there are 3 naming styles in the JSON.
I want to ask is there any way to set a handler or a subclass that can bind values correctly to POJO's fields in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@JsonProperty](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html), for more [examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#1-jsonproperty)

```
@Data
class A {

   @JsonProperty("hello_word")
   private String helloWorld;

   @JsonProperty("my-name")
   private String myName;

   @JsonProperty("Age")
   private Integer age;
}
```

Comment: @JsonProperty it works for me, but if there are lots of fields with different naming styles, configuration will be a hard work. The better way i think is inject a strategy into the deserializetion mechanism, but i don't know how.

Comment: If all of your fields are in different format then i don't see any other options @YuFangCheng